# offer created again after setting remote answer sdp webrtc android

Tags: android, webrtc

I  created an offer and sent it.I successfully received remote answer sdp and set it as remote description but as setting the remote answer sdp a new offer is again created and sent and new answer sdp is received. This cycle is going on. What could be the reason?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

If all callbacks are implemented correctly, such behavior should not happen. Check the sequence of your actions:

1. Create OFFER
2. Set it as local description (in onCreateSuccess callback) (**this is probably the step you missed**)
3. Send it to the other side via some signaling (in onSetSuccess callback)
4. Receive ANSWER from the other side
5. Set it as remote description

If you think that you do exactle the same, and the problem is still there, please post some code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did blunder by creating offer in onSetSuccess() so whenever the remote answer sdp is set the offer is created.I could resolve it

Comment: Glad I could help, @vinay:) If your problem is resolved, maybe you should mark the answer as correct.

Comment: @Vinay I'm using webrtc in my android app. Have used Twilio STUN and TURN servers. But the call takes too much time to get connected when using different networks. Could you please help me with it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631198/webrtc-takes-long-time-to-connect-on-mobile-data

Comment: @Alexey Ershov I'm using webrtc in my android app. Have used Twilio STUN and TURN servers. But the call takes too much time to get connected when using different networks. Could you please help me with it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631198/webrtc-takes-long-time-to-connect-on-mobile-data

Comment: @Arjun sorry, can't help you, haven't used WebRTC since 2015 :) You should probably ask Twilio support for help.